# SSL warnings while using Origin Certificate on my VPS

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, vps, cloudflare

I created Origin Certificate in cloudflare and installed on my Apache on Debian VPS using the guide https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217472077.

My URL is like this: https://socket.mydomain.com/

I am getting warning "There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)." whenever I visit above URL, why? Remember that I am not using old versions of browsers. Tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of warning you get? Check your site against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for the problem they report.

Comment: This question has been copied to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126153/ssl-warnings-while-using-origin-certificate-on-my-vps

Comment: The questions has been answered here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/126153/29034